# Select set of elements based on distinct conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of objects, with 2 attributes and a score.

An example as a pandas DataFrame:

```py
   name  length      age     score
0     a    long  archive  3.783075
1     b    long      new  1.374101
2     c    long  archive  2.966182
3     d  medium   recent  2.597856
4     e  medium   recent  4.660299
5     f    long      new  2.881734
6     g  medium  archive  0.504617
7     h    long      new  3.992420
8     i  medium  archive  1.358410
9     j    long  archive  1.381186
10    k   short   recent  0.752018
11    l   short  archive  4.939279
12    m    long  archive  3.455712
13    n   short   recent  2.715878
14    o   short   recent  3.768798
15    p   short      new  2.010524
```

I need to select 5 objects (names) from the list with the highest score, but following some criterea, such as "at least 2 need to be `length=short` and at least 2 need to be `age=new`, (but an element needn't neccisarily be both)".

Is this possible to do in a reasonably pythonic manor? Or is this problem not solveable and would require some approximation.

So far I have worked out that I can group by length and age into buckets, but then the challenge becomes working out what elements to choose from each bucket.

I've also experimented with ordering by score and just taking from the top, skipping elements that would be contradictions, but then I found I'd get the 5 I need, but not have filled in the one condition and then having to work out what to remove.

I could experiment with first selecting high scoring objects to fit the criteria, then fill in the gaps with whatever is left.

I have to filter through thousands of objects and choose the top 10. I am using SQL to narrow down to just searching the top 200 objects (to make whatever algorithm execute in a reasonable timeframe.) Maybe I could use the SQL query more effectively.
Would it be possible to filter more precisely (e.g. select 10 objects, 4 or more short and 2-5 long, 5 or more new or recent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
a = df.sort_values('score', ascending=False)
b= df.loc[df['length']=='short'].sort_values('score', ascending=False).head(5)
c = df.loc[df['age']=='new', :].sort_values('score', ascending=False).head(5)
d = pd.concat([a.iloc[:3,],b,c])
d.drop_duplicates().iloc[:10,]
```

**Details**

```
a = df.sort_values('score', ascending=False)
```

a is the dataframe with top scores at the top

```
b= df.loc[df['length']=='short'].sort_values('score', ascending=False).head(5)
```

b is the df with `length=short` and sorted by scores & only top 5 of those

```
c = df.loc[df['age']=='new', :].sort_values('score', ascending=False).head(5)
```

c is the df with `age=new` and sorted by scores & only top 5 of those

```
d = pd.concat([a.iloc[:3,],b,c])
d.drop_duplicates().iloc[:10,]
```

Then we create df d by concatenating only first 3 rows of (so that top scores are always present in d, no matter what) & with b & c.
Then we drop duplicates so that if items in a or b or c were present in each other, they get removed & we have unique values.
Finally we take only 10 rows in d.
You can play around with `head()` values & `iloc()` values to get the right mixture for your needs.

The result i got was

```
name    length  age     score
l   short   archive     4.939279
e   medium  recent  4.660299
h   long    new     3.992420
o   short   recent  3.768798
n   short   recent  2.715878
p   short   new     2.010524
k   short   recent  0.752018
f   long    new     2.881734
b   long    new     1.374101
```

Comment: This seems to be what I need, thanks so much. I noticed that by doing `a.iloc[:3,]` you're basically ensuring that even if `b` is fully used, there will be at least 2 items from `c` in the final list, same for the opposite way around.

Comment: Yes. Try it out.